# How to store a list of inputs for multi-thread programming

Tags: c, multithreading

Currently my program should take a list of numbers entered by the user at the command line and then find the sum of this numbers and print it out. My code is the following, I know to store a single number entered by the user, but what if I want a list of number, separated by space?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int sum; /* this data is shared by the thread(s) */
void *runner(char **); /* threads call this function */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
pthread_t tid; /* the thread identifier */
pthread_t tid2;

pthread_attr_t attr; /* set of thread attributes */

if (argc != 2) {
fprintf(stderr,"usage: a.out <integer values>\n");
return -1;
}

pthread_attr_init(&attr);

pthread_create(&tid,&attr,(void(*)(void *))(runner),(void *)(argv+1));

pthread_join(tid,NULL);

printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
}
/* The thread will begin control in this function */
void *runner(char **param)
{
int i;
sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
   sum = sum + atoi(param[i]);

pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I want to be able to enter a list of numbers in the command line, and store those numbers into a list and then find the sum of all those numbers.

, can someone tell me what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: you're not supposed to change your question content as people gives you corrections...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems here:

```
if (argc != 2)
```

This means you're expecting the integer values to be quoted, i.e. `a.out "1 2 3 4 5"`. If you do things this way the numbers are represented as a single string, i.e. `argv[1] := "1 2 3 4 5"`.

It's easier to check for `argc < 2` and taking the arguments as `a.out 1 2 3 4 5`. This way each argument gets its own string, i.e. `argv[1] := "1", argv[2] := "2"` etc.

You can of course use a quoted list instead, but then you have add some logic to extract the integers from the string (e.g. with `strtok`) whereas argument handling can do it for you instead.

Second, your program expects at least six integers here, and also skips the first one (you want `i` to go from `0`:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
   sum = sum + atoi(param[i]);
```

As for the upper limit, one way to convey the number of integers together with their strings is to use a struct:

```
struct arg_struct {
    int argc;
    char **argv;
};
```

and then use such a struct when calling `pthread_create`, i.e.

```
struct arg_struct args = { argc-1, argv+1 };
pthread_create(&tid,&attr,(void(*)(void *))(runner),(void *)(&args));
```

and change `runner` accordingly:

```
void *runner(struct arg_struct *param)
{
int i;
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < param->argc; i++)
   sum = sum + atoi(param->argv[i]);

pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Here's the code with all changes:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct arg_struct {
    int argc;
    char **argv;
};

int sum; /* this data is shared by the thread(s) */
void *runner(struct arg_struct *); /* threads call this function */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
pthread_t tid; /* the thread identifier */
pthread_t tid2;

pthread_attr_t attr; /* set of thread attributes */

struct arg_struct args = { argc-1, argv+1 };

if (argc < 2) {
fprintf(stderr,"usage: a.out <integer values>\n");
return -1;
}

pthread_attr_init(&attr);

pthread_create(&tid,&attr,(void *(*)(void *))(runner),(void *)(&args));

pthread_join(tid,NULL);

printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
}
/* The thread will begin control in this function */
void *runner(struct arg_struct *param)
{
int i;
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < param->argc; i++)
   sum = sum + atoi(param->argv[i]);

pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the help and explanation. May I ask one more question? How do I access the list of numbers that user entered? Because I want to do something more with the this list of numbers. I want to create another thread to find the min number of this list. I have the algothrim to find the min, `int smallest = INT_MAX;
for (i = 0; i < param->argc; i++)
  {
  if(atoi(param->argv[i])<smallest){
    sum=atoi(param->argv[i]);
}`  But as you can see I am trying to go through the list and compare each number entered and see if it's the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

It baffles me that you could write a threaded programme but did not know that:

you cannot <strike>cast</strike> parse an array of string to an array of int. you have to do the <strike>casts</strike> parsing one by one, during the sum loop.

```
/* The thread will begin control in this function */
void *runner(char **param)
{
int i;

sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= upper; i++)
    sum = sum + atoi(param[i]);
pthread_exit(0);
}
```

You also need to pass `argv+1` and not `argv[1]` to `pthread_create` in `main`:

```
// the runner function declaration
void *runner(char **);

// the thread creation
pthread_create(&tid,&attr,(void *(*)(void *))(runner),(void *)(argv+1));
```

Comment: thanks, but I got a invalid initializer error at `char *list[] = (char **)param;`

Comment: I got conflicting types for runner error, the thread runner that is

Comment: I'm not going to give it to you like that. What do you think could be the reason? A conflicting type happens when to different declaration/definitions don't agree (the error message should point it to you).

Comment: I forgot to change the prototype to same as void *runner(char **param). But I get seg. fault when trying to run the program. and also a warning of `warning: passing argument 3 of âpthread_createâ from incompatible pointer type` I dont think you can pass (char) to thread, it's suppose to be only void's

Comment: well, I guess we cannot avoid a cast on the function too

Comment: I believe you mean `(void (*)(void *))(runner)`.

Comment: Ok i edited the original post. added the changes. but it still does not store the list of numbers still. When I run it by `./prog.c 1 2 3` it still gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: Sorry, upon closer reading it should be a mix of what you had and what I suggested: `(void *(*)(void *))` (phew!).

Comment: are you sure you want to loop over the list of string 5 times?

Comment: @nemetroid thanks for your input. Doing all this from a cellphone isn't easy (my brain is not ready to simulate a C compiler down to that level of details yet)

Comment: @didierc someone should make a cdecl app. :-)

Comment: @nemetroid sure, that would make it a bit easier for me, all other things being equal.